# Using Java8 Stream to find the highest values from a List or Collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class to store user attempts.

```
public class UserAttempt() {
    private long userId;
    private long attemptNumber;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now, I have a collection of these objects:

```
List<UserAttempt> userAttemptList = new ArrayList<UserAttempt>();
```

One user may have a large number of attepmts.
So, I want to get a collection only with max attempt numbers of each user using java 8 streams.

Comment: Not really clear from the code what do you intend with *I want to get a collection only with max attempt numbers of each user*.. Maybe sharing what you've attempted further hints.

Comment: A single `UserAttempt` represents a user (by id) and an amount of attempts this user tried in a (somthing like a) session, is that correct, @Alex? You want to have a list containing only the *sesion* with the maximum amount of attempts per user id. That is how I understand this question... Is it right?

Comment: Did you search before asking? I don’t have a reference right here, but this question has been asked and answered with only minor variations a number of times. Your search engine will often give you a better answer faster than what you get from posting a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `toMap()` collectors with a custom merge function to collect the values into a `Map` where the key is the id and the attempt is the value:

```
Map<Long, UserAttempt> userIdToMaxAttempt = userAttemptList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        UserAttempt::getUserId, 
        Function.identity(), 
        (left, right) -> left.getAttemptNumber() > right.getAttemptNumber() ? left : right
    ));
```

If you only want to get the attempts, you can call the `Map#values()` method:

```
Collection<UserAttempt> attempts = userIdToMaxAttempt.values();
```